# session start event in my JS code

Tags: javascript, html, session, session-storage

Is there any way to capture the session-start event in javascript code?

What happens now is that I need to check on any page-load event if the sessionStorage has a specific key, and if it's false - I add the new key/value pair to the sessionStorage. 
Something like this:

```
if(sessionStorgae.Registered) {
    // do something
}
else {
    sessionStorage.SetItem("Registered", "0")
}
```

I would love to add the key without checking for its existence anytime a page loads. Is it possible with a kind of client session-start event?

I'll appreciate any suggestion,
Ben

Comment: Why do you need to set it to zero in the first place?

Comment: It's just an example, I don't really use this key/value pair

Answer (score 0):

You could simply listen to the `load` event of your document.
With jQuery, you would write:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Assume that sessionStorage is ready
});
```

If you don't want to listen to any page event, simply move your JS to bottom of your HTML page.

Comment: That's what I'm doing now, but I want to change this behavior and not to listen to any document ready event...